# How Do I Check For an Empty Object in a Meteor Template?

Tags: javascript, meteor, spacebars, meteor-helper

I have a template data context like this:

```
data = {
    "attribute1": {
        "attribute2": {}
    }
}
```

And in the meteor template I am doing something like this:

```
{{#with attribute1}}
    {{#if attribute2}}
        show some content
    {{/if}}
{{/with}}
```

I don't want to show anything if attribute2 is an empty object. However I tried both `{{#with attribute2}}{{/with}}` and `{{#if attribute2}}{{/if}}` And it's still rendering the content inside even if it's an empty object.

What is the correct way to check if the object is empty in spacebar template? Or is it even possible?

Comment: if you are using meteor with lodash you can do something like `#if _.isEmpty(data["attribute2"]) ` or `#if data["attribute2"].length > 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found a way to register a template helper and use [jQuery.isEmpty](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isEmptyObject/) to do the null check:

```
Template.registerHelper("isEmpty", function (object) {
    return jQuery.isEmpty(object);
});
```

And to use it in the template:

```
{{#unless isEmpty attribute2}}
    show some content
{{/unless}}
```

But I found a drawback from this solution that if I want to refer to attributes inside attribute2, I will need to add `{{#with attribute2}}{{/with}}` inside the unless block

Comment: It may be a drawback to have to add the `{{#with attribute2}}{{/with}}` inside of the `unless` block, but this is the only way that you can switch the context of the code block inside of the `{{#with attribute1}}{{/with}}` code block in the same template, unless you were to make the contents of the information to be displayed inside of the inner `{{#with}}` block defined within a separate template and then passed the `attribute2` object value to that template to set its data context to be `attribute2`, like so: `{{#unless isEmpty attribute2}}{{> templateName attribute2}}{{/unless}}`.

Answer (score 1):

if `attribute2` is an object, you can use `Object.keys` to check the length

```
{{#with attribute1}}
    {{#if !!Object.keys(attribute2).length}}
        show some content
    {{/if}}
{{/with}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your original code does not work is because you are assuming that an empty object equates to false in Spacebars. As mentioned [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/spacebars/README.md#ifunless) in the Spacebars documentation, only falsy Javascript values (`null`, `undefined`, `0`, `""`, and `false`) will be considered false by Spacebars. Therefore, an empty object needs to be checked using a Meteor helper method like your accepted answer suggests.